# Can jQuery manipulate HTML that is not on the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

For example:

I have the following HTML on the DOM:

```
<div id="hey"><h1>Trollin</h1></div>t
```

If this content was on the DOM, I could simply do:

```
$("#hey h1").text("Hello!");
```

But what if the HTML was stored in a JavaScript string called "myString"? Is it possible to change the text when it is not on the DOM using jQuery or must I append it, edit it and then remove it?

If it is not possible to edit the HTML using jQuery whilst the HTML is in the variable, what is my best option?

Comment: Does the HTML Display? Then it is in the DOM...  Though, I guess the better answer to your question is, yes, you can edit JS script tags

Comment: @Cheruvian No, that is my point, it is not on the screen it is stored in a variable.

Comment: [`$(myString)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) would convert the string of HTML (must start with a `<` character) to a jQuery-wrapped DOM fragment, which you can use all of jQuery's object methods on for manipulation.

Comment: @jskidd3 Might as well post it as an answer if it works for you :P

Comment: @George Please don't remove the JavaScript tag from jQuery posts: jQuery is still JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`$(myString)`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) would convert the string of HTML (must start with a `<` character) to a jQuery-wrapped DOM fragment, which you can use all of jQuery's object methods on for manipulation.

Comment: Looking at the others, this seems like the most logical. Thanks!

Comment: @jskidd3 You're welcome! If you end up wanting to put that fragment into the web page's DOM, make sure to `.append($(myString))` on something in the DOM. E.g. `var $myHtml = $(myString); /* do something to it */ $('.some-selector').append($myHtml);`.

Comment: @ajp15243: Does this actually inject anything into the DOM? The Docs make it sound like that is the case, but I always thought it was just a DOM-*ready* jQuery object.

Comment: @CaseyFalk I use it often, and no it does not inject the elements into the DOM. Are you wondering about the whole paragraph about the owner document? Having an owning document doesn't put the markup in the DOM.

Comment: @ajp15243: Exactly what I was curious about; thanks for clearing that up. :)

Answer (score 1):

`.parseHTML()` seems like what you're looking for. See the http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/.